# CSV file to browser from PHP

Tags: php, csv

I am using fwrite to create a csv file that will be output to the browser. I get a blank page, however when I dump my array, the array will show up. 
Here is my code:

```
$result = Camp::getAllCampers($camp);

header('Content-Type: text/csv'); 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=export.csv');

$fh = fopen('export.csv', 'w');

foreach ($result as $product) {
    $person = $product['Person'];
    $club = $product['Club'];
    $type = $product['Type'];
    $registeredby = $product['RegisteredBy'];
    $registereddate = $product['RegisteredDate'];
    $event1 = $product['Event1'];
    $event2 = $product['Event2'];
    $event3 = $product['Event3'];
    $event4 = $product['Event4'];

    fwrite($fh, "{$person},{$club}\n");
}

fclose($fh);
```

Comment: You're not writing anything to the screen.  `fwrite` writes to the handle opened by `fopen`, which is `'export.csv'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is what I came up with:

```
$result = Camp::getAllCampers($camp);

function makeCSV($table){
    $csv="";foreach($table as $r){$csv .= implode(",", $r).",\n";}return $csv;
}

$new_file_name = 'export.csv';

header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='.$new_file_name);
echo makeCSV($result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there, you are just missing the [readfile()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) call to send the file you've just created to the browser.